# Stroke order of 㠭

Tags: characters, writing, handwriting, stroke-order, strokes

I usually use [yellowbridge.com](http://www.yellowbridge.com/) when looking up stroke order, but they didn't have any information on 㠭.  This isn't the first time this has happened, but usually it's easy enough to guess.  However, in this case, I'm not sure whether I should right the top-right 工 or the bottom-left 工 first.  (After Googling a bit, everything I looked at said "top-to-bottom" and "left-to-right", but none of them said which of these two guidelines takes precedence.)

There isn't a double/triple 工 character like 林 or 森 is there?  If there were, I suppose that would dictate the proper stroke order.

Comment: For such rare words, stroke order really doesn't matter.

Comment: @PEMapModder There is no such rule as _"For rare characters, stroke order does not matter."_

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I mean, there isn't an entirely source of definition of stroke orders. Stroke orders are different in different places, so we can see that they are probably what becomes regular after wide usage. But for rare characters, they are rarely used, so I doubt if the rules for these characters can still be inherited. There are just generic rules, but not specific stroke orders, for characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right.

Edit: It is completely analogous to the stroke order of 叕 and other square quadruples.

Answer (score 4):

It is a rarely used Chinese character. It has two pronunciation: "zhǎn" and "zhàn".

English meaning: to open, to stretch; to extend, to unfold; to dilate; to prolong.

The radical of 㠭 is 工, such as the radical of 林 or 森 is 木.

The stroke order of 㠭 is
[image]

If you want to learn more common stroke orders of Chinese characters, I recommend to read [learn Chinese character stroke order](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/article/chinese-characters-learning-tips/chinese-character-stroke-order/).